# Memory addressing with C variables

Tags: c, byte, memory-address

If run, this program will output addresses with a 20 byte difference between them. Since both long and long * data types only allocate 8 bytes of information, why is there not an 8 byte difference between them? Where are the other 12 bytes going?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void functioner(long *y) {
    printf("functioner y address: %p\n", &y);

}

void function(long *x) {
    printf("Function x address: %p\n",&x);
    functioner(x);
}

int main() {
    long p =;
    printf("Address of p: %p\n", &p);
    function(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To maintain the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Comment: Not 20 bytes, 0x20 bytes. That's 32 in decimal.

Comment: You should read about the call stack structure. [This Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) entry is a nice starting point.

Comment: Are you known to the fact that you sent the function the pointer and then printed THAT POINTER address? A pointer is 4 bytes, doesn't matter the type. +Different functions have different memory spots. No one said it'll be that way.

Comment: @user3195614: A pointer is not 4byte everytime. And Techmaster21 said already 8.

Comment: @deviantfan my bad, I think I confused him, it depends on your OS, it'll be 4 bytes on 32 bits OS or 8 bytes at 64 bits OS.
Usually it'll be 8 if it's a modern computer

Comment: `long p =;` is a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

for one thing you are printing the address of the pointer, not the pointer.

```
void function(long *x) {
    printf("Function x address: %p\n", &x);
}
```

try this (remove the &):

```
void function(long *x) {
    printf("Function x address: %p\n", x);
}
```